# How to show non printing characters in nano

Tags: nano

Is there a way to show or toggle non printing characters like newline or tab in nano?

At first let's assume the file is plain ascii.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If it is not configured for "tiny", `nano` can display printable characters for <kbd>tab</kbd> and space, but it has no special provision for *newline*.

This is documented in the [manual](https://www.nano-editor.org/dist/v2.7/nano.html#Whitespace):

> `set whitespace` *"string"*
> Set the two characters used to indicate the presence of tabs and spaces. They must be single-column characters. The default pair for a UTF-8 locale is `"»·"`, and for other locales `">."`.

and can be enabled/disabled while editing:

> Whitespace Display Toggle **`(Meta-P)`**
>
> toggles whitespace display mode if you have a **`"whitespace"`** option in your nanorc. See [Nanorc Files](https://www.nano-editor.org/dist/v2.1/nano.html#Nanorc-Files), for more info.

Comment: On a MAC "Meta" key is the "esc" key by default.

Comment: on Windows via SSH it's ALT-P, though it didn't actually make any difference to what was displayed

Comment: Regarding pressing `(Meta-P)`: Is there a way to make this permanent, for example via a Setting? So we don't have to press (Meta-P) every time we open a file..